# Free up space on K3s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s, containerd

I have a K3s single-node cluster running with Containerd and where I'm reaching the space disk limit.

It seems I have some old unused docker images on the machine.

How can I cleanup those in order to free up the disk ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

After further investigation it seems it's more a volume (or several) from running container that is taking all the disk space.

How can I list the volumes used by the pods and their properties (disk etc..)

Answer (score 1):

### About the docker images

As mentioned in docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/)

You can use `docker image ls`  to list all images and `docker rmi` to delete them.

For example you can use

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

To delete all the images

---

### About disk space

You could try with [df](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/df-command-linux-examples/), [du](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/du.1.html) and kubectl [top](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#top)/[describe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe) commands.

```
df -h
du -sh . 
kubectl top/describe
```

You can list all Persistent Volumes and Persistent Volumes Claims with:

```
kubectl get pv --all-namespaces
kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces
```

You can list all Persistent Volumes sorted by capacity

```
kubectl get pv --sort-by=.spec.capacity.storage --all-namespaces
```

---

### Additionally look at these

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328104/how-to-get-containers-disk-usage-in-kubernetes-without-docker-command
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628539/disk-utilization-stats-per-pod-in-k8

---

Hope you find this useful.